# Wiremock :How to read the stub from a file in wiremock?

Tags: wiremock, stubbing

Currently I am setting up request and response in my stub through my java code like below.

```
wireMockRule.stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/abc/xyz"))
                .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                        .withBody("Hey")
                        .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                        .withHeader("Content-Type",
                                "application/text")));
```

I wish to know if there is a possibility that I define all the stub configuration in the json file like below and just read it in my java code.

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/abc/xyz"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "jsonBody": {"Hey"},
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/test"
    }
  }
}
```

I read about mapping folder over many post. I am not sure what that is and how do I get it and how can it help in my use case?

Also, I read about body file name but that just helps with the response body while I wish to find a solution which helps with the whole stub from a file.

A working java example would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you read http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/? *"To create the stub described above ... the following document can [be] placed in a file with a `.json` extension under the `mappings` directory"*

Comment: Yes I have. It says that a json file can be placed under the mapping directory. I am not sure how do I get the mappings directory? Do I create it manually? I am using wiremock in my spring boot project <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: So did you try looking that up? http://wiremock.org/docs/configuration/#file-locations

Comment: Earlier I placed the above json in "src/main/resources/__files/abc.json" and was trying to fetch the stub in my code by using "withBodyFile()" method. So I was getting whole file contents as response body. Instead I wish to get the whole file as my complete stub. Now I have placed the file in the mappings directory ("src/main/resources/mappings/abc.json"). How do I get this a s stub in my java code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It worked. Thanks. Stuck in on other problem, if you can help me. I am trying to define multiple stubs in one file with following format:  {
  "mappings": [
    {
      "request": {
        "url": "/multi/1",
        "method": "GET"
      },

      "response": {
        "status": 200
      }
    },

    {
      "request": {
        "url": "/multi/2",
        "method": "GET"
      },

      "response": {
        "status": 200
      }
    }
    }
  ]
}  I am getting Unrecognized field "mappings" (class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.StubMapping)

Comment: AFAIK to use multiple mappings in a single mapping file you'll have to add it via the admin console instead of just housing it in the `mappings/` directory. If you have it in the `mappings/` directory, then WireMock thinks it is a mapping to use, and throws you that error because `mappings: ` is an invalid field for a singular mapping. Info on admin console: http://wiremock.org/docs/api/ . I'd probably suggest that you have each mapping in a separate mapping file.

Comment: @agoff Thanks for your reply. As suggested, I am working with separate files in mappings folder. Wish to ask one more question. Is there any way by which we can make wire mock thread safe. I mean multiple test cases in a suite can run in parallel and since I am instantiating wiremock as WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8900); in each test case. So when they will run in parallel there will be clash for the port. How canI get over it?

Comment: If you don't need unique data per test, you can just have the one WireMock instance running. Instead of starting a new server for each test, just start the server before all tests and teardown after all are completed. If you need unique data and states, you'd have to spin up separate WireMock servers on separate ports.

Answer (score 2):

Stubs file (src/test/resources):

[image: stubs file in src/test/resources]

Content file (stub.json):

[image: content stubs.json file]

Comment: This means that you start the wiremock server in java programmatically and still take advantage of configuring the stubs using json file. Correct? Initially I thought you can only use the stubs in the mappings folder if you use the standalone jar process.

Comment: Yes, with java your can run and stop wiremock programmatically. You can use config json file or programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Actually wiremock under the hood just reads the files and maps them to a POJO. This can be seen by looking through the library source code ([JsonFileMappingsSource.loadMappingsInto](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock/2.10.1/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/standalone/JsonFileMappingsSource.html#loadMappingsInto(com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.StubMappings))).

So to achieve the same you can just do:

```
private static StubMappingCollection deserialize(String fileContent) {
    return com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Json.read(
        fileContent,
        StubMappingCollection.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can also set custom path to stubs in this way (version 3.3.1):

```
@Test
public void anyTest(WireMockRuntimeInfo runtimeInfo) {
    final WireMock wireMock = runtimeInfo.getWireMock();
    wireMock.loadMappingsFrom(rootDir);
}
```